# Opening Python and its files in Windows Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am currently reading the book Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw. On exercise 1 after learning the basics of Powershell we must open a notepad++ saved `.py` file in Powershell. Now here is the problem I'm having.

I am supposed to open this python file by running this command:

```
PS C:\Users\Trevor> python ex1.py
```

Zed Shaw does this in his book and it prints back what the file contains...("hello world")

Now i understand my path is wrong by the error message i receive telling me that python is not recognized. I have tried many many times to get the correct path to open python. I have saved the python27 file to my desktop and just about everything trying to get a path that will work.

I am starting at:

```
PS C:\Users\Trevor>
```

Any idea how to get to my python27 file and open python when it is saved to my desktop? I also have my ex1.py file saved to my python27 folder. Should i remove it? please help if you can thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell cannot find python in the current directory or in the directories specified in PATH environment variable.

You can add your installed python directory to PATH variable in System Properties (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → type in `sysdm.cpl`) → Advanced → Environment variables... → Under "user variables for ...", find PATH variable (if there aren't any, create it using New...), double click to edit it and insert "<your python path>;" (without the quotes). After that, restart PowerShell, run your command and you're done.

Comment: there isnt a variable called Path under my user variables.. so i need to create a new one? Also how do i know what to put? would it be my current path for example: `PS C:\Users\Trevor>` then the ;? or is is just the ;? Sorry im really quite new to this.

Comment: Python is usually installed in C:\Program Files\Python27 (if you still can't find it, make a full search on your computer for "python.exe"). And yes, as I mentioned, if there isn't Path, just create one and put "<path to python>;" there

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but for me the solution to it wasn't creating a path. I typed in the same code as you, and this is the error message I got:

**C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

The fix to this was a lot easier than I expected it to be, but it took me a little bit longer to figure out what it was since I just started learning how to work with Python and PowerShell.

This is what you need to do to solve this issue:

1. Instead of typing the name of the file you are trying to open, you first need to open the directory (the folder where all of your python files are stored).
2. To open the directory, type in cd DirectoryName and then press enter.
3. After that, type in "python" (without the quotes) and then the file name (for example, ex1.py). Then, press enter.
4. At this point, PowerShell should be able to open the file.

This is what you should see:

**PS C:\Users\UserName> cd DirectoryName**

**PS C:\Users\UserName\DirectoryName> python FileName.py**
(Note: This is when the file would print)

If your file still isn't opening, you may need to be more specific about the path to the directory. I have my directory located in C:\Users\UserName. If your directory is in C:\Users\UserName but you have it embedded within another folder, you may have to open that folder in PowerShell (you can do this by typing cd FolderName) before you can open the directory folder that's inside it. The easiest thing to do is to save your directory folder in the path C:\Users\UserName so that opening files will take less time/typing.

Comment: Hey! I think you've misunderstood the question, they were having troubles running Python in PowerShell instead of running a python file. It was a problem with his PATH configuration instead of python itself.